# How do i access and object attribute inside a list of objects given certain index?

Tags: python, list, object, indexing, attributes

In other programming languages, to access attributes in of a class instance you just do:

```
print(Object.Attr)
```

and you do so in python as well, but how exactly you get a certain attribute at a certain index in a list of objects, normally i'd do this:

```
ListObj[i].attr
```

but the object is in a list. I want to access a specific index inside the list and pull the object attributes inside that index.

Comment: Assuming `ListObj` is a `list` of objects, and the object you're interested in is located at index `i`, and you're looking for that object's `attr` attribute, `ListObj[i].attr` is exactly the way to do it.

Comment: In what way does your current code fail? It looks like it should work correctly if you are trying to access the attribute `attr` of the object at index `i` in list `ListObj`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, to access object attribute the syntax is

```
<object instance>.<attribute_name>
```

In your case, [index].

As Paul said, use `dir(<object_instance>[index])` to get all attribute, methods associated object instance.

You can also use for loop to iterate over

```
for <obj> in <object_list>:
    <obj>.<attribute_name>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can access the dict (a.k.a Hashtable) of all attributes of an object with:

```
ListObj[i].__dict__
```

Or you can only get the names of these attributes as a list with either

```
ListObj[i].__dict__.keys()
```

and

```
dir(ListObj[i])
```