# Addressing values stored within object that is within a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in some code I am writing, I have a list of objects. I also have a second list of objects, but these objects actually take the first list as a parameter(object-inception!).

Anyways, for both cases(If I can figure out how the first works, the same method may work for the second as well), I need to be able to address the data stored within a particular object after addressing that particular object's index.

Here is some Pseudo code for essentially what I would like to do.

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self, fruit)
        self.fruit = fruit
ObjectList = [Object("apple"), Object("banana"), Object("orange")]
newList = []
for i in ObjectList:
    newList.append(ObjectList[i].fruit)
```

Likewise, if I were to pass this list of objects(we will call it a list of object A) as a parameter into another object(object B), and then made a list of those objects(as as many layers as you would like to go, honestly!), I imagine that I could use the same method to extract object A list out of each object B within the object B list, and then extract the desired data out of each object A from the object A list.

For me personally, this is one of the most advanced programs I have written, and since I am new to Python I could be doing it entirely wrong. Any help or suggestions will be well taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simpler example, but solving the same issue, I actually managed to find the answer. This is just so anyone coming across this will know where to find the answer they need.

[How do i access and object attribute inside a list of objects given certain index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540746/how-do-i-access-and-object-attribute-inside-a-list-of-objects-given-certain-inde)